# Getting Mysql2::Error (SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation) on Heroku App with AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, amazon-web-services

`Mysql2::Error (SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation):`

I am making an administration site. The environment is Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2, connecting AWS RDS with Heroku server.
I don't know why getting this error. It suddenly appeared. I can't find any errors other than this. Although I passed my codes two days ago, I got this error this time.(I haven't touched this code while the two days.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And then, I thought this error was caused by [SSL Certificate Rotation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.Rotation). I confirmed ssl certificate is updated, rds-ca-2015, and already rebooted, but nothing changes. I'm still stacked! Please help me!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For me, this had to do with the RDS SSL Certificate Rotation that happened on April 3rd, 2015.

However, in my case, just using the root certificate did not work, and I had to use a intermediate certificate for my region as well.  Details:

1. Go into the AWS rds console and reboot your RDS instance.
2. Download the new root certificate https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem.  Put it into the config directory of your app.
3. Download the intermediate certificate for your database region
   [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html).  I had to use the US east one, but you will have to pick the one for your region.
4. This is the key step.  You need to combine the intermediate certificate and the root certificate into one file so that the intermediate certificate is above the root certificate, forming a certificate chain.  Open the intermediate certificate using a text editor, copy its contents, and paste them into config/rds-ca-2015-root.pem, on top, above the root certificate.  So, after you are done, config/rds-ca-2015-root.pem should be the intermediate certificate followed by the root certificate, all in this file.
5. Get your current database url

```
heroku config
```

and then look for the DATABASE_URL property

5. Update your database URL to use the new certificate file.  All you should have to change is the name of the certificate (since its now called
   rds-ca-2015-root.pem)

```
heroku 
config:add DATABASE_URL="mysql2://DB_NAME:DB_PASSWORD@DB_URL/DB_NAME?sslca=config/rds-ca-2015-root.pem"
```

6. Commit the changes and redeploy to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, @guidoprincess! I could fix this haunted problem. I'd never have been aware of needing to add the intermediate certificate if you hadn't notified me. In addition to this, do you know the reasons why the codes I didn't add intermediate certificate to certificate file have passed until April 3rd, 2015?

Comment: The short answer: no :) . The long answer: the certificates changed over on April 3rd, and I assume with that change came some sort of new heightened level of security which required an intermediate certificate!  Also, can you please accept the answer as correct if it helped you!  Thanks.

Comment: Great assumption! I appreciate it.

Comment: Ditto... It works now. As guidoprincess suggests, just make sure the DB was restarted after Apr. 3rd: mysql <<< "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';"

Comment: Merging the files did it for me. Prior to reading your answer I had no idea that I needed two files.

Comment: Not sure why the cert chain mechanism wasn't working but this also fixed for me, need combo file

Comment: If you're using node, don't forget that `fs.readFileSync` [only reads the first certificate and it can't read certificate chains](http://www.benjiegillam.com/2012/06/node-dot-js-ssl-certificate-chain/). I've spent hours just to figure out why mysql only reads the 1st certificate.

Luckily, I managed to read the cert chains by using arrays to read the file, or use a module like [split-ca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-ca).

Comment: Just the root cert worked fine in aws eu-west-1 up until this week. Dunno what changed.

Answer (score 2):

Four years later (2019) and AWS are rotating CA certs again, as expected.

RDS users are recommended to switch from the 2015 cert to the 2019 cert by 2019-11-01, and "no later than" 2020-02-05. The 2015 certificates expire on 2020-03-05.

I used the following procedure, based on RDS' [Rotating Your SSL/TLS Certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html) guide.

1. Schedule downtime
2. [Download](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) new certificates, save in `config`

- Only the root cert is needed: `rds-ca-2019-root.pem`

  - The instructions mention a 2015+2019 bundle, but I couldn't find it. This file is 2019 only.
- Region-specific intermediate certs are not needed

1. Commit, but don't deploy yet
2. `heroku maintenance:on`
3. In RDS web console, modify server

- In the Network & Security section, choose `rds-ca-2019`
- Apply changes immediately

1. Scale dynos down to 0
2. `heorku config:set DATABASE_URL=mysql2://myuser:mypassword@myhost.rds.amazonaws.com/mydb?sslca=config/rds-ca-2019-root.pem`
3. Deploy
4. Scale dynos up, watch logs
5. `heroku maintenance:off`

There are many reasonable variations on this procedure, this is just what worked for me.