# SSL connection error when trying to connect to mysql Aurora via the mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I will preface by saying I can connect to the DB instance when I'm not trying to go over SSL.

I am following this guide here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html

I have ensured the db instance is public facing.

The security group of the VPC has the following rules:

```
Type Protocol Port Range Source
MySQL/Aurora (3306) TCP (6) 3306 my_ip_address/32
MySQL/Aurora (3306) TCP (6) 3306 sg-security_group_name
```

Where the security_group_name is the security group for my EC2 cluster.

I am using the cluser endpoint of my aurora cluster. And I've removed the port. I installed mysql on my machine using homebrew. This is the command I am trying from my local machine (macbook):

```
mysql -h blah-database-cluster.cluster-dfgdgfd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert
```

Where rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem is the file I downloaded from here:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

I have tried creating a new instance, rebooting etc and no joy. Does my security group need some kind of https rule?

Edit:

Further clue. When I run mysql --ssl locally it doesn't error. But when I do mysql show_variables, it says SSL false and the have_ssl and have_open_ssl variables don't exist. Could this be the problem? I installed the local mysql via homebrew package manager for mac.

New edit:

I re-installed mysql (previously from brew) and now direct from oracle and when I try to connect it **gives a different error - SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation**

Comment: It's definitely not in the security group, since MySQL (unlike http) has a mechanism for negotiating the use of SSL and a separate port isn't needed.  Out of curiosity, you are using the full DNS hostname when connecting, yes?  What happens if you omit `--ssl-verify-server-cert`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes I'm using the full hostname. If I omit verify server cert I get the same error. If I omit ssl complete and try an ordinary mysql command line connection I can get in. I am thinking this means something about my client side mysql and ssl isn't working. I've noticed that have_ssl and have_open_ssl variables don't exist too

Comment: Is the time on your local machine correct? Drifting clocks can cause errors with SSL.

Comment: @MikeRyan Yes it's correct. It's in a different time zone to the server, but locally here the time is correct.

Comment: Ok, timezones won't be an issue. Does it work if you connect directly to one of the DB node endpoints? i.e. not the cluster endpoint.

Comment: @MikeRyan The cluster endpoint and the node end point are both the same. Perhaps it's because there is only one node in the cluster? I re-installed mysql (previously from brew) and now direct from oracle and when I try to connect it gives a different error - SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I re-installed mysql (previously from brew) and now direct from oracle and when I try to connect it gives a different error - SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation

Comment: Have you tried loading the intermediate certs as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29467638/394423 You'll need to make sure your client is using the intermediary cert too.

Comment: @MikeRyan Yes I tried that. I think that was a one-off scenario when AWS changed their certificates around and some people were affected. In the modify instance section of the database it's not even possible to change the certificate (the guide says its a textbox to type in and to type in the intermediate certificate but it's now a select box and it's fixed and can't be changed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. At present the AWS Aurora documentation is linking to an out of date SSL certificate to use, hence the problem. This has been confirmed by the AWS support staff. Use this instead: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
2. Even when using that certificate, connecting to the cluster end-point over SSL still doesn't work for the command line using mysql -h connection. If I change from the cluster end-point to the instance end-point strangely it works.
3. Bizarrely, mysql workbench does connect over ssl, both to the instance end-point AND the cluster-end point.

Comment: Same issue here ... cluster won't connect, instance is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql with --skip-ssl option if you not using SSL.If nothing helps upgrade your mysql client

Comment: Also there may be some other ssl options in your my.cnf which will cause same failure.
You can ignore my.cnf file with --no-defaults like:
mysql --no-defaults -h yourserver.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com  --ssl-ca=/etc/app-ssl-rds/rds-ca-2015-us-west-2-bundle.pem -uyouruser -p

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Aurora.html) it appears the restriction to the instance endpoint for SSL connections is a security constraint associated with the certificate.

> Amazon RDS creates an SSL certificate and installs the certificate on the DB instance when Amazon RDS provisions the instance. These certificates are signed by a certificate authority. The SSL certificate includes the DB instance endpoint as the Common Name (CN) for the SSL certificate to guard against spoofing attacks. As a result, you cannot use the DB cluster endpoint to connect to the primary instance of the DB cluster using SSL.

Comment: Just a FYI, that wasn't in the docs at the time I created this question.

Comment: No problem. I came across it and put the blurb here so I could find it later.

Answer (score 0):

FYI
please try using this key as well (from Amazon docs)

https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to use:

`mysql --ssl-mode=DISABLED -u [USER] -p[PASSWORD] -h [HOST] [DB]`