# Connecting to RDS Postgres from Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm in the process of migrating my Heroku app database from Heroku to AWS RDS Postgres.

On my computer, I can connect to my RDS DB using:

```
psql -d "postgres://user:password@XXX.rds.amazonaws.com/mydb?sslrootcert=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem&sslmode=require"
```

However, the same psql command run from within my heroku server just hangs forever.

Also, `config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem` is the RDS certificate that I added to my package as mentioned in the documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#authorizing-access-to-rds-instance and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467638/943524 (I did combine certificates as I am using a eu-central-1 instance).

Would someone have an idea what is blocking the connection here ?

Comment: https://www.wootric.com/blog/how-we-migrated-from-heroku-postgresql-to-aws-rds/ I haven't read it yet but a co-worker sent it over to me for just this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sound of it, your Network ACL or Security Groups are blocking your access. It looks like they allow your computer (perhaps your entire company’s IP) but not Heroku. Check out the NACLs and Security Groups and you should find your answer (i.e. add Heroku IP range to your NACLs and/or Security Groups).

Comment: You were right. The thing is the NACL was already configured to allow my laptop IP whereas I never added it, so they must do it themselves by default, which is surprising and lead me to believe 0.0.0.0/0 was the default.